# Adding images to excel header using spreadsheet gear?

Tags: c#, image, excel, header, spreadsheetgear

I'm using the latest Spreadsheet Gear and C# on .NET 3.5

I'm generating a spreadsheet and adding various formatting to it.  One thing I would like to do is add an image to the left header section of my spreadsheet for printing.  How do I achieve this?

I have tried:

```
worksheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = Image.FromFile("file location");
```

but that doesn't seem to work.  When I look at an example in Excel, I notice that excel sees a headed picture as "&[Picture]", but doesn't specify a file path.

Does anyone know the solution to this?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, did you find out how to do this?

Comment: I created a workaround:  My image was essentially fancy text with lots of colors.  I came up with 2 ways of embedding the text.  1- make an excel file as an embedded resource with all the header formatting you need and just open that with SSG.  2- save an excel file with all the formatting you need in the xml format and inspect it with something like notepad++ to see what excel is representing the data as.  In my case, I needed a navy color and excel was calling it something like `&20&K04-024text` for size 20 navy text.  As far as I can tell, it's not possible to put an image in the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a workaround: My image was essentially fancy text with lots of colors. I came up with 2 ways of embedding the text. 1- make an excel file as an embedded resource with all the header formatting you need and just open that with SSG. 2- save an excel file with all the formatting you need in the xml format and inspect it with something like notepad++ to see what excel is representing the data as. In my case, I needed a navy color and excel was calling it something like &20&K04-024text for size 20 navy text. As far as I can tell, it's not possible to put an image in the header.

Answer (score 3):

A little late, but here we go:

You we're right with the first line:

```
worksheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "Filename or URL"
```

but you missed the second command:

```
xlsheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&G"
```

there is the usual problem with different languages. For example, if you'd prefer to use Excel in German this tag becomes ="&I" (for no obvious reason)

You can adjust your image with the usual commands.